# How can I easily extract that data-expanded-url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, perl

I'm trying to parse an HTML webpage for a URL that is defined as `data-expanded-url`. There is only one URL to extract and only one `data-expanded-url`. Here is the main portion of the webpage where all the stuff I'm doing is happening:

```
<p class="js-tweet-text tweet-text">The Air <strong>Jordan</strong> 11 Retro
<strong>Low</strong> &#39;<strong>Nightshade</strong>&#39; is <strong>now available</strong>
    <a href="http://tt.co/5w574TicgS" rel="nofollow" dir="ltr" data-expanded-url="http://swoo.sh/1fKCmCB" class="twitter-timeline-link" target="_blank" title="http://swoo.sh/1fKCmCB" >
        <span class="tco-ellipsis"></span>
        <span class="invisible">http://</span>
        <span class="js-display-url">swoo.sh/1fKCmCB</span>
        <span class="invisible"></span><span class="tco-ellipsis">
        <span class="invisible">&nbsp;</span></span>
    </a>
    <a href="http://tt.co/Ug4qjrW9DD" class="twitter-timeline-link" data-pre-embedded="true" dir="ltr" >pic.twitter.com/Ug4qjrW9DD</a>
</p>
```

This is the part of that section with `data-expanded-url`:

```
<a href="http://tt.co/5w574TicgS" rel="nofollow" dir="ltr" data-expanded-url="http://swoo.sh/1fKCmCB"`
```

How can I easily extract that `data-expanded-url` with something like [Mojo::DOM](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Mojo::DOM) or [HTML::Parser](http://www.metacpan.org/module/HTML::Parser) or XPath?

Comment: I had to change the t.co to tt.co because SO won't allow that domain in any of the text, including the literal text. :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is code you need:

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();

my $url = "https://twitter.com/search?q=from%3Anikestore%20%22jordan%22%20%22nightshade%22%20%22low%22%20%22now%20available%22%20since%3A2014-5-2&src=typd";

$mech->get($url);

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content( $mech->content() );

my ($link) = $tree->findvalues('//p[ @class =~ /\btweet-text\b/ ]/a[1]/@data-expanded-url');

$tree->delete();

print $link, "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks that works to get the t.co before which in this case works great! But is there a way to get the                              `data-expanded-url="http://swoo.sh/1fKCmCB"` after it but still thanks a lot this will work for now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [Mojo::DOM](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Mojo::DOM) example:

```
use Mojo::DOM;

my $html = do { local $/; <DATA> };

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new( $html );

say $dom
    ->find( 'a.twitter-timeline-link' )
    ->map( attr => 'data-expanded-url' )
    ->grep( sub { defined } )
    ->join( "\n" );
```